# My app stopped logcat error

Tags: logcat

I have this error and i don't know why!

> 04-28 09:26:55.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1437): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 04-28 09:26:55.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1437): Process:
>   com.neurondigital.HighwaySpeed, PID: 1437
>
> 04-28 09:26:55.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.neurondigital.HighwaySpeed/com.neurondigital.HighwaySpeed.HighwaySpeed}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> 04-28 09:26:55.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
>
> 04-28 09:26:55.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>
> 04-28 09:26:55.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>
> 04-28 09:26:55.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>
> 04-28 09:26:55.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>
> 04-28 09:26:55.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>
> 04-28 09:26:55.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>
> 04-28 09:26:55.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 04-28 09:26:55.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>
> 04-28 09:26:55.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>
> 04-28 09:26:55.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>
> 04-28 09:26:55.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):   at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 04-28 09:26:55.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1437): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> 04-28 09:26:55.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):   at
>   com.neurondigital.HighwaySpeed.HighwaySpeed.onCreate(HighwaySpeed.java:40)
>
> 04-28 09:26:55.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>
> 04-28 09:26:55.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>
> 04-28 09:26:55.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>
> 04-28 09:26:55.935: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):   ... 11 more

This is the code:

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Context;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.os.PowerManager;

import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock;

import android.view.Display;

import android.view.KeyEvent;

import android.view.Window;

import android.view.WindowManager;

import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;

public class HighwaySpeed extends Activity {

    Surface view;
    WakeLock WL;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //full screen
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        //wake-lock
        PowerManager PM = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        WL = PM.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "Graphics");
        WL.acquire();

        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        int rotation = display.getRotation();
        if(rotation == 0)
            view.default_lanscape = true;
        if(rotation == 180)
            view.default_lanscape = true;
        if(rotation == 90)
            view.default_lanscape = false;
        if(rotation == 270)
            view.default_lanscape = false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
            view.back();
            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        view.pause();
        WL.release();
    }

    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        view.resume();
        WL.acquire();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        WL.release();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At HighwaySpeed.java:40 there's a NullPointerException

If you attach the code it's easy to resolve the problem.

EDIT:
You have to write `view = new SurfaceView(this);` at the beginin of `onCreate` method to avoid the NullPointerException.

The main problem is that you don't initialize the variable, but there is other errors in the code, for example the class Surface hasn't got a default_lanscape attribute and you're triying to initialize it in `view.default_lanscape = true;`

Comment: i copy the HighwaySpeed.java, can you see the problem??

Comment: I can't see line 40, but it seems that the view variable isn't initialized.

Comment: so, what should i do?

Comment: Probably `view = new SurfaceView(this);` solve NullPointerException.